# How do I compile a .c file on my Mac?

Tags: c, macos

How do I compile a .c file on my Mac?

Comment: Probably because all the answers are quite out of date. Any .c file can be added to an Xcode project and added to a target. Then it will compiled along with all the .m (Objective-C) files or Swift files.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You will need to install the [Apple Developer Tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/). Once you have done that, the easiest thing is to either use the Xcode IDE or use `gcc`, or  nowadays better `cc` (the clang LLVM compiler), from the command line.

According to Apple's site, the latest version of Xcode (3.2.1) only runs on Snow Leopard (10.6) so if you have an earlier version of OS X you will need to use an older version of Xcode. Your Mac should have come with a Developer Tools DVD which will contain a version that should run on your system. Also, the Apple Developer Tools site still has older versions available for download. Xcode 3.1.4 should run on Leopard (10.5).

Comment: Hi Adam, is the gcc from Apple Developer Tools a symbolic link to clang c compiler or it's a real gcc c compiler?

Comment: Just for anyone googling here, this QA is some **ten years old** (!!!)  This answer is (utterly) out of date, the modern answers down the bottom explain how to do it easily these days.

Answer (score 62):

You'll need to get a compiler. The easiest way is probably to install XCode development environment from the CDs/DVDs you got with your Mac, which will give you gcc.
Then you should be able compile it like

```
gcc -o mybinaryfile mysourcefile.c
```

Comment: what would those DVD's say on them. i have two. one is a start up disk i think and the other says aplications on it.

Comment: @David: I'm not a mac user, but since you're trying to install some applications, you might try the one that says applications. (And if I'm wrong, well, try the other one)

Comment: I'd bet it's on the Applications CD. I only have the snow Leopard upgrade DVD (and that's just a single DVD), and XCode is in "Optional Installs/Xcode.mpkg"

Answer (score 33):

In 2017, this will do it:

```
cc myfile.c
```

Comment: Perhaps the question could be more specific. My interpretation is that it asks how to install a compiler on macOS

Comment: It’s 2023, that’s what worked for me (after installing Xcode dev tools)

Answer (score 32):

Just for the record in modern times,

## for 2017 !

1 - Just have updated Xcode on your machine as you normally do

2 - Open terminal and

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

it will perform a short install of a minute or two.

3 - Launch Xcode.  "New" "Project" ... you have to choose **"Command line tool"**

Note - confusingly this is **under the "macOS" tab**.

[image: choose this one]

Select "C" language on the next screen...

[image]

4- You'll be asked to save the project somewhere on your desktop. The name you give the project here is **just the name of the folder** that will hold the project. It does not have any importance in the actual software.

5 - You're golden! You can now enjoy c with Mac and Xcode.

[image: you're golden]

Answer (score 7):

You can use gcc, in Terminal, by doing gcc -c tat.c -o tst

however, it doesn't come installed by default. You have to install the XCode package from tour install disc or download from http://developer.apple.com

Here is where to download past developer tools from, which includes XCode 3.1, 3.0, 2.5 ...

http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.3.3.3.1

Comment: I went on apples site and they only had Xcode for snow lepord. which i don't have. Where can i find an ealeir version of Xcode on their site? or will the version they have up work for me?

Comment: You should be able to find an older version there as well, not just the Snow Leopard one. If not, it might be on your install DVD in the "Extras" folder which corresponds to your OS. I believe XCode 3.0 was compatible with Leopard, and possibly 3.1 as well.

Comment: Added URL to the Apple Connect site where archived XCodes are available.

Answer (score 3):

Ondrasej is the "most right" here, IMO.
There are also gui-er ways to do it, without resorting to Xcode.  I like [TryC.](http://homepage.mac.com/nsekine/SYW/software/english/tryc/index.html)

> Mac OS X includes Developer Tools, a developing environment for making
>   Macintosh applications. However, if someone wants to study programming
>   using C, Xcode is too big and too complicated for beginners, to write
>   a small sample program. TryC is very suitable for beginners.

[image]

> You don't need to launch a huge Xcode application, or type unfamiliar
>   commands in Terminal. Using TryC, you can write, compile and run a C,
>   C++ and Ruby program just like TextEdit. It's only available to
>   compile one source code file but it's enough for trying sample
>   programs.

Comment: TryC crashes at the frequency of rainy season downpour.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `gcc` compiler.  This assumes that you have the developer tools installed.

Answer (score 1):

STEP 1

Just check wheater your MacBook has the compiler or not using this command  `clang --version` in your command line interface.  If the tool exists then you will be able to see the version like this[image: command line interface]

STEP 2
Next, go to the directory where your source code exists using CMD Interface, then run the command `make "filename"` without the .c extension.

STEP 3
The final command to run your source code after compiling it is `./filename` without the .c extension.

This is how you can compile and run your program on the Macintosh system.