# Problems installing Yeoman Generator

Tags: node.js, yeoman-generator

Like many, I'm also having problems installing the Yeoman generator. I've looked at many of the examples in Stackoverflow and I've tried a number of my own solutions but I haven't been able to make it work. Any help I could receive to solve this problem would be much appreciated. I tried installing yo angularfire and sudo angularfire.

Thank you.

Here is my error list:

```
  npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0'
    npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0']
    npm ERR!   errno: 3,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   path: '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0',
    npm ERR!   parent: 'imagemin' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! cwd /Users/mac/mcoseo7
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! path /Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno 3
    npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0'
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

app/index.html modified.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:86:
../src/constants.cc:10:66: warning: template argument uses unnamed type [-Wunnamed-type-template-args]
  object->Set(NanNew<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone"), NanNew<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone));
                                                                 ^~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:290:1: note: unnamed type used
      in template argument was declared here
enum {
^
1 warning generated.
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node: Finished

    npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9'
    npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9']
    npm ERR!   errno: 3,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   path: '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9',
    npm ERR!   parent: 'phantomjs' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "karma-phantomjs-launcher" "karma-jasmine"   
"grunt-karma" "--save-dev"
    npm ERR! cwd /Users/mac/mcoseo7
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! path /Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno 3
    npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9'
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

White-Macbook-2:mcoseo7 mac$ grunt
>> Local Npm module "grunt-autoprefixer" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-imagemin" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-google-cdn" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-newer" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-ng-annotate" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-svgmin" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "newer:jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Aborted due to warnings.

Again, than you for the help!

Comment: If the generator is or depends on a [native addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) module, this will need to be compiled on your machine [using `node-gyp`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-gyp). For OS X, [C/C++ compilers are bundled with Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603489). From the `node-gyp` "Installation" docs: "*Note that OS X is just a flavour of Unix and so needs `python`, `make`, and C/C++. An easy way to obtain these is to install XCode from Apple, and then use it to install the command line tools (under Preferences -> Downloads).*'

Comment: I don't want to use xcode and I don't know why that's even being brought up. I just want to use a regular IDE. I get this error for xcode when I try to install any of the generators.

Comment: You don't have to use Xcode for all of your development. But, you'll need to have `python`, `make`, and C/C++ compilers installed for `node-gyp` to succeed when installing some Node.js modules/packages. The latter are part of Apple's "command line tools" and can be installed through Xcode (or [possibly without](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/how-to-download-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode-without-the-downloads-for-devel)).

Comment: I went to Apple and downloaded the command line tools for OS X 10.7.5 and installed on my Macintosh hard drive. Now what?

Comment: I get some different errors than I was before. Thanks for taking a look!