# How can I run a C program on Mac OS X using Terminal?

Tags: c, macos, bash

I am new to C. Here is my "Hello, World!" program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

After I try to run it using Terminal it says:

```
/Users/macbook/Desktop/peng/Untitled1

-bash: /Users/macbook/Desktop/peng/Untitled1: Permission denied
```

Why?

Comment: See [How do I compile a C file on my mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603489/how-do-i-compile-a-c-file-on-my-mac)

Comment: What is file "Untitled1" ? Is the file who contains the source you have included in the question or anything else?

Comment: Replace `pintf` by `printf`, keep int and main on the same line.

Comment: The canonical question: *[How can I compile and run C/C++ code in a Unix console or Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/)*

Answer (score 217, accepted):

First save your program as `program.c`.

Now you need the compiler, so you need to go to **App Store** and install **Xcode** which is Apple's compiler and development tools. How can you find **App Store**? Do a *"Spotlight Search"* by typing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and start typing `App Store` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when it guesses correctly.

**App Store** looks like this:

[image]

**Xcode** looks like this on **App Store**:

[image]

Then you need to install the command-line tools in **Terminal**. How can you start **Terminal**? You need to do another *"Spotlight Search"*, which means you type <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and start typing `Terminal` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when it guesses `Terminal`.

Now install the command-line tools like this:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then you can compile your code with by simply running `gcc` as in the next line without having to fire up the big, ugly software development GUI called *Xcode*:

```
gcc -Wall -o program program.c
```

**Note**: On newer versions of OS X, you would use `clang` instead of `gcc`, like this:

```
clang program.c -o program
```

Then you can run it with:

```
./program
Hello, World!
```

---

If your program is C++, you'll probably want to use one of these commands:

```
clang++ -o program program.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -o program program.cpp
g++-7 -std=c++11 -o program program.cpp
```

Comment: Make it `gcc -Wall -o program program.c` and you'll get helpful compiler warnings (though not all of them) that will tell you some of the reasons your code isn't working.

Comment: Nice answer, but note that there is no need to explicitly invoke clang - gcc is symlinked to clang anyway.

Comment: And plain `cc` is symlinked to both of them — that's all I ever have to type.

Answer (score 67):

First make sure you correct your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello, World!\n"); //printf instead of pintf
   return 0;
}
```

Save the file as `HelloWorld.c` and type in the terminal:

```
gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.c
```

Afterwards, just run the executable like this:

```
./HelloWorld
```

You should be seeing *Hello, World!*

Comment: Better to "save the file as *Untitled.c*". Even better yet: use a more meaningful filename.

Answer (score 17):

A "C-program" is not supposed to be run. It is meant to be compiled into an "executable" program which then can be run from your terminal. You need a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) for that.

Oh, and the answer to your last question ("Why?") is that the file you are trying to execute doesn't have the executable rights set (which a compiler usually does automatically with the binary, which let's infer that you were trying to run the source code as a script, hence the hint at compiling.)

Comment: best answer! `A "C-program" is not supposed to be run.`

Comment: I believe a reasonable answer to this SO question should include instructions on how to compile and execute a program written in C. This answer does not contain any such instructions, therefore downvote. Please let me know if you disagree.

Comment: Alex, you may feel free to add another answer.

Answer (score 17):

***This is Working in 2019***

By default, you can compile your *name.c* using the terminal:

```
 cc name.c
```

And if you need to run, just write

```
 ./name.out
```

Comment: its showing up as "a.out" instead of f"{name}.out" no matter what the name is. its always "a" for some reason.

Comment: @Flaming_Dorito, that's the default behaviour to create the executable object file. You can however choose to give it a name of your liking. 
Type -> cc -o name name.c

Comment: @YashTamakuwala ohh I see. Thanks

Comment: Using `cc` is unusual. Presumably it is some kind of alias. Perhaps add a reason and a source for it (e.g., to some standard documentation)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: cc works on OSX Monterey. 

`which cc` tell me  `/usr/bin/cc`  and `file /usr/bin/cc ` says 
`/usr/bin/cc: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` [...]

Answer (score 7):

To do this:

1. Open the terminal
2. Type in the terminal: `nano` ; which is a text editor available for the terminal. When you do this, something like this would appear.
3. Here you can type in your C program
4. Type in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> → which means to exit.
5. save the file by typing in <kbd>Y</kbd> to save the file
6. Type the file name; e.g., *helloStack.c* (don't forget to add **.c**)
7. When this appears, type in *gcc helloStack.c*
8. And then `./a.out`: this should give you your result!

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"something like this would appear"*. Was a screenshot intended? Or something else?

Answer (score 4):

For compiling a C program on your latest macOS, just type the following in the terminal after saving the file with a .c extension and on reaching the path where the file is saved:

```
cc yourfilename.c
```

Once you have checked all the errors after compilation (if any), type the following for executing the code:

```
./a.out
```

These commands are tested on [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave) and are working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

To compile a C program in macOS, simply follow the below steps

Using the *cd* command in terminal, go to your C program location and then type the command present below:

```
make filename
```

then type

```
./filename
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *chmod [755](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-755/) hello* - it makes the file executable... I had same problem on macOS, which is now solved.

```
nano hello.c
make hello
chmod 755 hello
```

Then you run it by *./hello*

```
clang --version
```

Output:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
```

Nothing was installed. nano make (clang) chmod - all inside macOS already.

Comment: What is the purpose of the last sentence? Can you elaborate? Preferably by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64616916/edit) (changing) your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, GCC (executable `gcc`) is installed by default in `/usr/local/bin`.

To run C:

```
gcc -o tutor tutor.c
```

Comment: Re *"To run C"*: Don't you mean *"To compile"* or *"To run GCC"*? Or *"To compile a C program"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66201243/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Actually, no, it isn’t. Gcc hasn’t been part of Xcode for ages, but clang is. And there is an alias that will call clang if you try to call gcc.

Answer (score -2):

1. First you need to install a GCC *compiler* for Mac (google it and install it from the Internet)
2. Remember the path where you are storing the C file
3. Go to Terminal and set the path

   E.g., if you have saved in a new folder *ProgramC* in the *Document* folder.

   Then type this in Terminal:

   ```
   cd Document
   cd ProgramC
   ```
4. Now you can see that you are in folder where you have saved your C program (let you saved your program as *Hello.c*)
5. Now *compile* your program

   ```
   make Hello
   ./hello
   ```