# clang compiler not working on terminal Mac OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, terminal, clang

I just upgraded to El Capitan and found out that the C compiler (Clang) is not working under the command line. I wrote a "hello word" test, tried to compile and I get the following error:

$ cc test.c -o test

$ error: unable to open output file

```
  '/var/folders/Ge/GeRStfi8Ek8jojLcqf1vsE+++TI/-Tmp-/test-ad7039.o': 'No

  such file or directory'
```

1 error generated.

... do I have a permission problems somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the file?

Comment: Try re-installing Xcode and the commandline tools ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32338889/2836621

Comment: it doesn't compile anything... and also I reinstalled Xcode with no use :(

Comment: What does `which cc` and `cc --version` say?

Comment: $ which cc gives /usr/bin/cc (which is simbolically linked with clang) and cc--version produces Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Check your permissions (try running with sudo). It's probably a permissions issue if the compiler can't open the output file.

Comment: will try with a workaround as El Capitan doesn't allow you manually to fix your permissions :(

Comment: Wait, it totally does. Have you tried using chmod or chown?

Comment: It is indeed a permission problem as I can actually compile the file using sudo. I tried repairing manually the permissions using the command line with:

sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /

 
and

sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /

 
but still I cannot compile without the sudo command

Answer (score 0):

Either you're running into permissions problems (the compiler is unable to create a folder inside `var`, and so there's no such file or directory) or the ability to open the file in the current directory of compilation isn't allowed. Check your permissions on

- The file
- The directory

Run the command under `sudo`. If that fixes your problem, then use `ls -la` to check your permissions in the current folder. Then, use [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) or [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) to change the permissions on the file/folder.

Example:

```
chown owner-user test.c
```

Now, you may actually not actually have access to the /var/ folder. If so, then the temp folder cc is creating is the problem. So then, you'd sudo call `cc`. For a more permanent fix, you can `chown` the binary or directory `clang` is in.

Comment: the sudo works, so I can live with it now :0 thanks for that... regarding permissions I am stuck here as the System doesn't allow me to change them! see this: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201560

Comment: ok... I found out how to do it under the command line here http://lifehacker.com/verify-and-repair-permissions-from-the-command-line-in-1741718667 will see how does it go

Comment: It is indeed a permission problem as I can actually compile the file using sudo; I tried repairing manually the permissions using the command line with:

 

sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /

 

and

 

sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /

 

but still I cannot compile without the sudo command