# How do I run C programs on a Mac?

Tags: c, terminal

I am new to C and am trying to figure out how do I run my code.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

I just want to run this simple Hello World program but I don't know how to.
I am using sublime if that helps.

Comment: maybe check this out: [How to run C program on Mac OS X using Terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32337643/1248974)

Comment: Go to the directory the file is saved in in terminal, then run `make [filename]` then run `./[filename]`

Comment: Also, you don't need to include stdlib

Comment: ... in this case.  Because you don't rely on anything declared therein.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, that's what I meant. Obviously you need to for some programs.

Comment: This might be better asked on [Apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com) since getting a C compiler on OS X is very Mac specific.

Comment: @Schwern cc and c99 aren't parts of POSIX?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Huh? I think you're making a very narrow reading of the literal question title and none of the rest of their question. They're asking how to run a C program, but don't know what a compiler is. Presumably they come from a background of interpreted languages and so expect something like "ruby program.rb" or even some IDE thing. OS X does not come with a C compiler and it has to be installed in a specific way. Installing a compiler, using the compiler, and running the resulting program are all parts <strike>this complete breakfast</strike> a complete answer.

Comment: I responded to your comment, not to the Q. You do not have to install Xcode to get a C compiler under macOS. You can install it the "usual" way. Installing Xcode is the easiest way and therefore the recommended way. The explanation is shorter than your last comment. After installing it you can use it the POSIX way.

Answer (score 1):

Use the C compiler from terminal in Mac, like:

```
cc -o outputFileName inputFileName.c
```

The output file is executable, so you can double click it or in the terminal simply provide the path to the file. If your working directory is already holding that `outputFileName` (check with `ls -al`) then you can type:

```
./outputFileName
```

The program will then execute.

Comment: Please always advise people add `-Wall`. It staves off a whole bunch of otherwise obvious "why isn't my program working" questions.

Comment: I'd add `-Wextra` too.

Comment: @Schwern This was *not* the Q. Without `-Wall` the standard is applied. However, one should add `-Werror`, too.

Comment: Please add the command to start the program.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - indeed it was the question.  It is always the question.  If it's not the question, then it's still the question.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I'm not that religious. But I'm surprised that remembering all the questions programming language and compilers in general and C in particular ask us, these hundreds and thousands of questions one can have, that there is a church of -Wall. (And obviously there is another confession -Wextra.)