# C HelloWorld exec format error

Tags: c, macos, clang

I am trying to compile and run my first code in C.

I used [this code](http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/c/hworld.html):

**HelloC.h**

```
#include<stdio.h>

// added int to prevent warning
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
```

I tried compiling with [these instructions](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_9.html)...

```
gcc -Wall HelloC.h -o HelloC
chmod +x HelloC
```

...and [this top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337643/how-to-run-c-program-on-mac-os-x-using-terminal) (same thing but replace `gcc` with `clang`).

**The Problem:** In both cases `./HelloC` returns `exec format error: ./HelloC`.

## **My Setup**

**OSX: 10.12.4**

clang --version

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

gcc --version

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Why is your code in a `.h` file?

Comment: How did you decide to use `chmod`?  That isn't part of the instructions you link to.

Comment: 1) Code should reside in `.c` files, not `.h`. 2) Functions that take no arguments should look like `func_name(void)` to avoid being called with arbitrary amounts of arguments. 3) You should actually `return` something from `main`. 4) Your compiler should make the output file executable automatically - if you ever have to use `chmod`, that's a bad sign.

Comment: Thanks, see my answer. I think I misread something else when I was naming the file, but now I understand. I used `chmod` because trying to run the .h file gave me a  permission error, and I was going to worry about that later but turns out that was part of the same problem.

Comment: @Siguza About 2), I have a Java background where void cannot be placed as a parameter and I'm perfectly comfortable with leaving the space between the parenthesis blank. Is it just an old convention or does it affect compilation or runtime in any way?

Comment: @MattGroth Yes it does affect compilation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/693788) and [this example](https://ghostbin.com/paste/tk9fs) that compiles with no error or warning. C treats `()` as "unspecified" rather than "no arguments".

Comment: I see, and so passing arguments to a method with unspecified parameters causes no error. Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: @Siguza: A `return 0;` at the end of `main` is unnecessary as of C99.

Comment: This is no way releated to gcc. Read the messages, just because you use the command `gcc` does not mean it **is** gcc. (Blame Apple for this stupid confusion!)

Comment: @Olaf I'm aware now that most of my question was irrelevant. Would it be better for me to remove the Setup section and simplify the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @ScottHunter and @Siguza

I needed to use .c not .h as the file extension.