# Mac OS X Can't install build-essential via brew or apt-get

Tags: macos, homebrew, apt-get

So I've been trying for two days to unsuccessfully install build-essential on a Mac OS X Sierra with `brew` and `apt-get`. Researching into the issue has given me some results but nothing that has yielded any results.

```
sudo apt-get update
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
```

Being lazy I've also listed below the other packages I'm struggling to install and their respective errors below.

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential

E: Couldn't find package build-essential
E: Couldn't find package libfreetype6-dev
E: Couldn't find package automake
E: Couldn't find package postgresql-9.5
```

Theres been a couple of suggestions to edit the source list of apt-get but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What on Earth are you doing? macOS doesn't use `apt-get` - at all. It doesn't come with a package manager.

There are independent package management tools, to my mind the best of them is **homebrew** from [here](http://brew.sh). Some folks use MacPorts.

Before you can do any development in macOS, you need Xcode's command-line tools - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338889/2836621).

If you want Postgresql, I suggest you go to the **homebrew** website above, copy the one-line install and paste it into Terminal. Once you have that set up, you can install **Postgresql** with:

```
brew install postgresql
```

If you want to search for package abcXYZnnn, just search for any part of that name:

```
brew search XYZ
```

If you want to do updates, and upgrades:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

If you want to remove a package:

```
brew rm PACKAGENAME
```

Comment: You can get `apt-get` on macOS : https://thecustomizewindows.com/2013/11/how-to-install-apt-get-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Homebrew:

```
brew install gcc binutils bison
```