# (Xcode), first time Objective C for pointer study - do i need more libraries?

Tags: c, pointers

```
(#) include < stdio.h >

int main () {

    int a = 10;
    int *p;

    p = &a;

    //Pointer arithmetic

    printf("Address p is %d\n", p);                       //error here
    printf("Value at address p is %d\n", *p);
    printf("Size of integer is %d bytes\n", sizeof(int)); //error  
    printf("Address p+1 is %d\n", p+1);                   //error as well
    printf("Value at address p+1 is %d\n", *(p+1));

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, as you see above, i am studying pointers under Objective-C. 
Note: This is my first time studying under Xcode version 8.3.3 using my Mac Sierra 10.12.5.

What I am experiencing in errors is that, and i quote: **"Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' "**.

Am I needing to download additional libraries or is their something i'm missing - to knock out this error?

Really appreciate the help and as well the Terminal code to help fix this error.

Please and thank you - and apologies, this is my first time using stack-over-flow question and site.

Comment: The error message is clear. The type of `p` is `int*` but `%d` expects an `int`.

Comment: Sorry....I did not understand the question. Was the message unclear? I believe it would have also pointed out the line number containing the mistake...right?

Comment: You don't need more libraries, but a good C book. Read the chapter about types. And this is not specific to ObjC.

Comment: @MichaelWalz So, how would i write in code to fix it? (Thank you for getting back to me - and would appreciate the use of you editing my code so i can see how it is to be written in C, for future use.)

Comment: @Olaf What book would you recommend?

Comment: @SouravGhosh If your talking about the error message: it reads as fallows "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' ". If i am answering you correctly

Comment: The one you find yourself. SO provides a list. Go, find it!

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointers and don't forget to cast its argument to `void*`. `sizeof` returns `size_t` and the correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: Why not OP let find out? The message could not be more clear.

Comment: @SirLockInBottom I don't mean to disrespect you, but a closer look would reveal something like `prog.c:12:27: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]`...so it says I have a problem in line 12, column 27....that should be enough indicator to pinpoint the erroneous instruction.

Comment: @Olaf We do have developer.apple website that i have been looking into, but using them still reaches a dead end.

Comment: As I said: learn the basics! C is no language for trial&error learning. And websites or youtube are a bad idea for learning, too.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Its alright dude, i am not disrespected at all really, haha. What i really want is an answer to my problem so i can continue coding with ease. And since your getting an error like that in Xcode (if your using it). Then, how would you rewrite, my code for it to function perfectly without any errors?

Comment: @Olaf I do have a book called Data structures using c and C++ by Yedidya * Moshe* Aaron. 2nd edition. Will it provide anything - assuming you heard of these authors - i've been getting a lot of "Oh his or her, book is better" which makes it much more difficult to learn code since their are so many authors for the same subject. (thanks by the way)

Comment: From the title, I'd throw it away. C and C++ are different languages, a book trying to cover both is already a major fail. It also seems to be directed to people knowing the languages already. I repeat: _you_ need the basics! And this is not a chatroom, so, that's all I have to say about this.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for that, i will try to find a better book to describe the Basics.

Comment: @SirLockInBottom Welcome to Stack overflow. Suggestions for books usually start to get opinionated and the discussions usually go no where. So we avoid suggesting any books explicitly. Still, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) question which mentions some really good books.

Comment: @SirLockInBottom Coming to your problem, what you have done is you are trying to print an address but in the printf format specifier you have written %d. A %d is used when you want to print an integer. An integer is not a pointer and is also not convertible as such. If you actually want to print the pointer you need to change %d to %p in the first printf (and also the one with p+1). Finally also cast p to `void*` as `(void*) p`.

Comment: @SirLockInBottom Regarding what @SouravGhosh was saying, that is a very important point. You need to learn how to interpret the error messages. I am not aware of Xcode but usually all compilers give a very descriptive error message which should point you to the most probable error site. Usually the error message is also accompanied with a line number. If your compiler doesn't have such error messages (or if the IDE is hiding them) I suggest use some other compiler. I believe you are using a Mac for development. So `clang` should be a good choice.

Comment: @SirLockInBottom AFAIK Xcode must be configured to use `clang` as a compiler. But you can manually invoke the compiler from command line (with appropriate flags so it shows you all errors and warnings).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Appreciate the help, the %p manage to turn it to Hex form - which is good enough to understand the address. I will use clang as a new IDE rather than Xcode and will see how that goes. I don't really know how to manually do the invocation for flags. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @SirLockInBottom hex is usually a good notation to read addresses because in decimal the numbers tend to get very large and all the "good" sizes like 16 bytes, 1024 bytes, 4096 bytes look better in hex. `clang` is not an IDE but a compiler. An IDE uses a compiler internally. You can invoke a compiler manually from a terminal. The flags which I mentioned are usually passed along with the file name to the compiler. You can type `clang --help` to see a list of all flags. The flag `-Wall` should be enough for you and will display all warnings.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Umm, quick question what if the Zip file of Clang ends up opening another zip file on-top of another zip file? Is that suppose to happen?

Comment: @SirLockInBottom I am guessing you are trying to install clang. I have a feeling your machine must already have it installed. In a terminal try running `cc --version` and check if it prints anything which says `clang ...`. If yes, you can directly start using `cc` as a compiler. You don't need a zip file.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Ummm. . .We have a problem, using the terminal dose not have -Wall on it. So whats the next step?

Comment: @SirLockInBottom What was the result of `cc --version` in the terminal?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Here is what i got on the cc --version:                    **cc --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin**

Comment: @SirLockInBottom Great! You already have clang installed. You can start using it directly. Type in `cc --help` and it will have all information on how to use the compiler.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya So i will be using the terminal itself to write in C, correct?

Comment: @SirLockInBottom You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337643/how-to-run-c-program-on-mac-os-x-using-terminal) for help on how to compile C code from the terminal and run it. You can write the code anywhere. In a normal text editor, Xcode anything. Just save it as a .c file and use the terminal to compile and run it. For beginner users it is advisable to use a text editor/IDE. You can continue using Xcode to write the code.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I'm actually getting more confused, so after knowing that my version of C is correct, and that the Terminal itself for getting Xcode downloaded; i can now write code on the Terminal? (I'm Dyslexic so i apologies for my . . . mental shortcomings.)

Comment: @SirLockInBottom Not a problem at all. So you see you need a text editor to write the code. You can write from the terminal but it might be a difficult to use. Given that you are already familiar with Xcode, use that to write the code. Then save the file as a .c file. You can then use the terminal to compile and run the code.

Comment: @SirLockInBottom if terminal is too confusing, you can continue to use Xcode as before(for everything), just pay more attention to the Warnings and errors it displays.

Comment: `(#) include < stdio.h >` shouldn't compile. Change to `#include <stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

- `%d` is a format specifier. `%d` in particular is used to print arguments of type `int`.
- `p` is not an `int`, it is a pointer to int, type `int*`.
- To print pointers, use the `%p` format specifier.
- `*p` is however of type `int`, since you de-referenced the pointer. For such arguments you should use `%d`.

As a side note, the result of `sizeof` isn't `int` but another integer type called `size_t`. To print this one, you need to use `%zu`.

Comment: Overall, don't spend too much time learning about the obscure stdio.h library. It has lots of complexity and is also generally dangerous. It is rarely used in professional production code.