# Compiling through macOS Terminal, fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, macos, gcc

So was trying to compile a c file (via a makefile) and got the "fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory" . This compiles on just fine via cygwin and a remote linux box just not my mac (so the files are okay).

I have installed the mac command line tools as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580758/gcc-fatal-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory) question. When I do gcc --version I am getting 5.3 but if i do brew info gcc i get 8.2.  When I do a find through terminal I can the file, so not sure what is up.

Comment: You need to think about whether your program is C or C++ as you seem to confuse the two at every step. Use `g++` for C++ programs and tag C++. Use `gcc` for C programs and tag C. Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338889/2836621

Comment: Mark yes you are correct, I was using the terms incorrectly, my bad. However, this still doesn't solve the underlying issue.  The Makefile I built works just fine (and uses gcc as its a c not c++ program) via Cygwin on my PC and my remote Linux server. However, I get the error I mentioned when running the makefile on my mac, so its something with my gcc install/version/? and my mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run:

```
which gcc
```

you will get `/usr/bin/gcc` which is the compiler supplied by Apple as part of macOS.

Presumably, since you mention **homebrew**, you mean to use the compiler installed by **homebrew**. So, you need to look in `/usr/local/bin` and see what **homebrew** has installed:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/gcc*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  29 17 Sep 10:53 /usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -> ../Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gcc-8
```

So, the answer to your question is:

- firstly, you need to have `/usr/local/bin` at the start of your PATH, and
- secondly, you need to use the following command to compile:

`gcc-8 main.c -o main`

Answer (score 0):

try running following:

```
xcode-select --install
```

See:
[GCC fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580758/gcc-fatal-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
for details.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I have already done that and it did not resolve the issue. The files are fine, the code compiles and runs on my PC and remote linux box. The only issue is trying to compile on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

With Mojave and XCODE 10, the problem is that the "include" folder is no longer automatically included when you install the command line tools.  Instead, you need to do an "open" on /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg 
That solved the identical problem for me, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and this is how I resolved it.

```
softwareupdate --all --install --force
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Basically developer framework is likely to be broken. But simply running `xcode-select --install` may not work because it will say the xcode developer tools are *already* installed (despite its broken status). So I had to completely wipe out any existing installation and install the developer framework again.

FYI if everything is installed correctly, the header files should be found at:

```
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```