# How to change the following Makefile so that it works for MacOS?

Tags: c, linux, macos, makefile

I used to do C programming in Linux. Now,I got MacBook and I want to do programming on the Mac.

How should I change the following makefile ?

```
# Makefile

OBJS = main

$(OBJS): $(OBJS).o
#   gcc -O2 -Wall $(OBJS).c -o $(OBJS)  -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib64   -leggx -lX11 -lm
    gcc $(OBJS).c -o $(OBJS)  -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib64   -leggx -lX11 -lm

$(OBJS).o: $(OBJS).c
    gcc -c $(OBJS).c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
     rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS).o
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't have to? What problems do you have with the makefile in its current form? What happens when you use it and run `make`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain why you need to change the Makefile. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am trying to compile my c program code .The error I get is " fatal error: eggx.h file not found'.EGGX is a graphic library which is used as a header file in my program.I thought that it's a problem of makefile ,so i requested a help here.

Comment: Why did you revert the grammatical fixes?

Comment: I am sorry, its by a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to review at least the following:

- do you want to continue to use `gcc` as your compiler, or move to Apple's `clang`
- if you want to use X11, you will need to install **XQuartz** and add the following options:

  `X11FLAGS=-I /opt/X11/include`
  `X11LIBS=-L /opt/X11/lib -lx11`
- you can remove `/usr/local/lib64` because **macOS** doesn't use that
- you will want to decide it you are going to use a package manager, such as **homebrew** because Apple doesn't provide one. Associated with that, you may want to use `pkgconfig` from **homebrew** to automate your compiler and linker flags and switches.

You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338889/2836621) helpful, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621).

---

I modified the `Makefile` included in the `egg` package to look like this and it compiles and builds fine on my Mac under macOS Mojave:

```
CC    = gcc
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall
DESTDIR =
USERCC   = gcc
USERCCFLAGS = -O2 -Wall
USERFC   = gfortran
USERFCFLAGS = -O2 -Wall

IINC  = -I/opt/X11/include
LLIB  = -L /opt/X11/lib

PREFIX = /usr/local

INCDIR = $(PREFIX)/include
LIBDIR = $(PREFIX)/lib
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

LOCALINC = -I$(INCDIR)
LOCALLIB = -L$(LIBDIR)

LLINKS = -leggx -lX11 -lm

DEFS = $(VDEFS) $(TDEFS) $(UDEFS) $(PDEFS) $(XDEFS)

all:: _xslave_ mkexheader exec_xslave.h lib egg

install:: lib egg
    if [ ! -d $(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR) ];then sh install-sh -d $(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR); fi
    if [ ! -d $(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR) ];then sh install-sh -d $(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR); fi
    if [ ! -d $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR) ];then sh install-sh -d $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); fi
    sh install-sh -m 644 libeggx.a $(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)
    sh install-sh -m 644 eggx*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)
    sh install-sh -m 755 egg $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)
    ranlib $(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/libeggx.a

.c.o:   ; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IINC) $(DEFS) -c $*.c

_xslave_: _xslave_.o _eggx_scrollbar.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) _xslave_.o _eggx_scrollbar.o -o _xslave_ $(LLIB) -lX11

mkexheader: mkexheader.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) mkexheader.o -o mkexheader

exec_xslave.h: mkexheader _xslave_
    ./mkexheader _xslave_ > exec_xslave.h

eggx_base.o: exec_xslave.h

lib:: eggx_base.o eggx_color.o
    ar cruv libeggx.a eggx_base.o eggx_color.o
    ranlib libeggx.a

egg:: egg.sh
    cat egg.sh > egg
    rm -f egg.t
    for i in USERCC "x@@$(USERCC)" USERFC "x@@$(USERFC)" \
      USERCCFLAGS "x@@$(USERCCFLAGS)" USERFCFLAGS "x@@$(USERFCFLAGS)" \
      IINC "x@@$(IINC)" LLIB "x@@$(LLIB)" LOCALINC "x@@$(LOCALINC)" \
      LOCALLIB "x@@$(LOCALLIB)" LLINKS "x@@$(LLINKS)" ; do { \
      if [ -f egg.t ] ; then \
        if [ "$$i" = "x@@" ] ; then \
          cat egg.t | sed -e "s|@@@TARGET@@@||" > egg ; \
        else \
          cat egg.t | sed -e "s|@@@TARGET@@@|$$i|" | sed -e 's|x@@||' > egg ; \
        fi ; \
        rm -f egg.t ; \
      else \
        cat egg | sed -e "s|@$$i@|@@@TARGET@@@|" > egg.t ; \
      fi ; \
    } done
    chmod 755 egg

clean::
    rm -f *.o *.exe egg egg.t libeggx.a _xslave_ mkexheader exec_xslave.h
```

If you saved the `tarball` of `eggx` in directory `HOME/eggx`, you would need to do this:

```
cd $HOME/eggx
tar -xvf eggx-0.93r5.tar
cd eggx-0.93r5
```

Then copy the modified `Makefile` from above and save it in that directory as `Makefile`. Now just run:

```
make
```

and it should all build fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204584/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-setchell-how-to-change-the-following-makefile-so-th).