# What is a replaceable command of "make-j" in Ubuntu for Mac?

Tags: macos, makefile

While following the steps from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vJJMU2gMn4 around 2:11, the video shows to run "make -j" in Ubuntu to start build. Since I'm using a Mac, I would like to know if there is any way that I can replace this commend. It seems "make" is a tool to install many packages in Ubuntu, which I think that can be replaced by "brew", but I'm not sure about the "-j" part.
Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: `make` is installed as part of **macOS** so it should be fine. The `-j` parameter only sets the degree of parallelism, i.e. the number of jobs to run in parallel and **macOS** *"understands"* that too. You can safely omit it if it is upsetting you and you don't mind waiting longer. Remember to install Xcode before you do any development on a Mac... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338889/2836621

Comment: Just to note, it's not a good idea to use `-j` by itself.  You should use a number there which corresponds roughly to the number of CPUs you have on your Mac, so something like `-j4` or `-j8`.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you all for your comments. :)