# Compiling C file in OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I am not familiar with OS X at all, and I need to compile a C file. Here is the code I use in Linux. What is the OS X version of those?

```
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -fpic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -c myfile.c -o myfile.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o myfile.so myfile.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many times need this be asked? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603489/how-do-i-compile-a-c-file-on-my-mac .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), which is free, and will allow you to install `gcc` just by typing `gcc` in Terminal. From there on, you can just compile `.c` files using it. Also, you might want to just type `gcc myfile.c -o myfile` instead of adding all of those flags, because the OS X filesystem hiearchy is different from that of Linux, and adding those extra flags might make the command not work.

Comment: You don't need Xcode.  Like you said, just typing gcc in Terminal on an OS X system will install the command line tools, but a full Xcode install is not needed.  Also, it is more than just a matter of the OS X filesystem layout being different from Linux.  /usr/bin/cc and /usr/bin/gcc on OS X are actually the clang compiler, and not gcc.  The OS X linker (see man ld) is also completely different from the usual Linux linker (supplied by the GNU Binutils package).