# Compile a C file in the Mac Terminal whit Header

Tags: c, macos, terminal, header-files

Sry for my bad english.

I want to compile in the mac terminal a c file name: "test.c"
and a headerfile name: "mylib.h" . How i can do it.

Comment: "gcc mytest.c". If you don't have GCC, install Xcode from the App Store and try again.

Comment: It may depend greatly on what is contained in those files. It is unusual to have one single `.c` and one single `.h` file, to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
gcc test.c -lmylib -o mycompiledtest
```

This assumes the .h file lives in the same folder as your .c file and if you have a library named "`mylib`" (for which the mylib.h file exists), you should include it after the `-l` bit in your `gcc` line

[More information about gcc found here](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.htm).

If gcc isn't found for you, try installing from the "command line tools" installer found at the [Developer Tools download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)(you'll need to sign in with your Apple ID).

Answer (score 0):

See this to know how to compile a c program on your mac: 
[How do I compile a .c file on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603489/how-do-i-compile-a-c-file-on-my-mac)
 (basically, install GCC).

For including the header file in the same path, #include "mylib.h" should work on GCC. See this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_2.html#SEC6