# Why does the terminal keep returning a zsh parse error no matter my input?

Tags: c

I am incredibly new to the C language: I am trying to run sample C programs from codecademy, such as the hello world command below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  // output a line
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Bottom line is, every time I try to run any code in my macOS terminal, I always get the following error:

zsh: parse error near `\n'

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2603489/4788546, https://www.google.com/search?q=compile+c+file+linux&rlz=1C1CHBD_enRO881RO881&oq=compile+c. [\[SO\]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546) explains the process (but on *Win*).

Comment: because you are trying to run the code in zsh instead of compile it with a C compiler

Answer (score 1):

[c](/questions/tagged/c) is a language where you need to *compile* the code you've written. You do that by starting a `C` compiler and give the file containing your C code as input.

Example:

File: `myfirstcprogram.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Then at the [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) prompt, invoke the compiler:

```
cc myfirstcprogram.c -o myfirstcprogram
```

`-o myfirstcprogram` is here an argument to the compiler telling it what to call the final program.

`cc` may be `clang` or `gcc` or any other compiler you've got installed if `cc` isn't already linked to the proper compiler.

When the compilation is done, the executable `myfirstcprogram` should have been created. You can now run it from your [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) prompt:

```
./myfirstcprogram
```

You can run it without recompiling it as many times as you like. Only when you change the source code (`myfirstcprogram.c`) do you need to compile the program into an executable again.